# Sqoop is failing to get data from teradata with java.IO exception

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

Here is my sqoop import that I'm using to pull data from Teradata

```
     sqoop import -libjars jars --driver drivers --connect connection_url -m 1 --hive-overwrite --hive-import --hive-database hivedatabase --hive-table hivetable --target-dir '/user/hive/warehouse/database.db/table_name' --as-parquetfile --query "select c1,c2,c3, to_char(SOURCE_ACTIVATION_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SOURCE_ACTIVATION_DT,to_char(SOURCE_DEACTIVATION_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SOURCE_DEACTIVATION_DT,to_char(EFF_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as EFF_DT,to_char(EXP_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as EXP_DT,to_char(SYS_UPDATE_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SYS_UPDATE_DTM,to_char(SYS_LOAD_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SYS_LOAD_DTM from source_schema.table_name WHERE to_char(SYS_UPDATE_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')> '2017-03-30 10:00:00' OR to_char(SYS_LOAD_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > '2017-03-30 10:00:00' AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

Below is the error I'm getting, this was running fine for two days and started returning the below error recently.

```
17/03/29 20:07:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/03/29 20:56:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1487033963691_263120_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.14] [Error 1005] [SQLState HY000] Unexpected parcel kind received: 9
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:94)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:69)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveRecordSubState.action(ReceiveRecordSubState.java:195)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:311)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:200)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:137)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.PreparedStatementController.run(PreparedStatementController.java:46)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.fetchRows(StatementController.java:360)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDResultSet.goToRow(TDResultSet.java:374)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDResultSet.next(TDResultSet.java:657)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:237)
    ... 12 more
```

When i googled around I've seen people getting same errors for different errors, I know this is something related to the time i'm using in where clause, but not sure what exactly i have to change.

Thanks in advance...!!

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop uses `$CONDITIONS` to fetch metadata and data.

- **Metadata** - It replaces `$CONDITIONS` with **1=0**. So, no data will be fetched using this condition but only metadata.
- **Data in case of 1 mapper**: It replaces `$CONDITIONS` with **1=1**. So, all the data is fetched.
- **Data in case of multiple mapper**: It replaces `$CONDITIONS` with some range condition.

Try these queries in JDBC client:

- > select c1,c2,c3, to_char(SOURCE_ACTIVATION_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SOURCE_ACTIVATION_DT,to_char(SOURCE_DEACTIVATION_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SOURCE_DEACTIVATION_DT,to_char(EFF_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as EFF_DT,to_char(EXP_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as EXP_DT,to_char(SYS_UPDATE_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SYS_UPDATE_DTM,to_char(SYS_LOAD_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SYS_LOAD_DTM from source_schema.table_name WHERE to_char(SYS_UPDATE_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')> '2017-03-30 10:00:00' OR to_char(SYS_LOAD_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > '2017-03-30 10:00:00' AND 1=0"
- > select c1,c2,c3, to_char(SOURCE_ACTIVATION_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SOURCE_ACTIVATION_DT,to_char(SOURCE_DEACTIVATION_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SOURCE_DEACTIVATION_DT,to_char(EFF_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as EFF_DT,to_char(EXP_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as EXP_DT,to_char(SYS_UPDATE_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SYS_UPDATE_DTM,to_char(SYS_LOAD_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as SYS_LOAD_DTM from source_schema.table_name WHERE to_char(SYS_UPDATE_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')> '2017-03-30 10:00:00' OR to_char(SYS_LOAD_DTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > '2017-03-30 10:00:00' AND 1=1"

If these are not working, your sqoop command with this query can never run.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable information dev. Both the quires are running successfully, But the issue is at the source I'm dealing. Data at source is recast to one date which has huge amount of records and the functional user I'm using has a time limit.